# Using HTMLParser to Parse a Table in Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing

I want to parse an HTML table into a 2d array (rows and cols) in python using HTMLParser (only. Don't want to use BeautifulSoup and other non-standard libraries)

This is for a personal project, doing this for fun :P

Anyway, here's my code. Its giving me a really messed up error - it says

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked what you exactly want to do, but you assign a string to `self.txt` and then try to use it as a list.

In the constructor, you initialize self.txt with an empty list :

```
def __init__(self):
...
self.txt = []
...
```

and then in the handle_data method :

```
def handle_data(self, text):
    if (len(self.txt) > 0 ) :
        self.txt.append(text + " ") # <-- Here you consider self.txt is a list

    if (self.in_table == 1 and self.in_th == 0):
        self.txt = text.lstrip() # <-- Here you **assign a string** to self.txt
```

Comment: Could you check what I did though? I'm trying to get done with this today... Basically I'm trying to add the dehtml'ed data to a new list and then joining the list elements to create one big blob of dehtml'ed text..  That's why self.txt is a list